# Google Maps compatibility with different Android versions/devices

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've developed an Android application that uses Google Maps API v2 to display a map that show the user location, different other points (shops...), a tracking blue point that represents the user when he moves and direction to a specific location.

All of this is correctly working on some devices, but not on others, and I don't know why?

Works well with Android 4.2.2, 4.3, 2.3.7

But not with Android 2.3.6, 4.0.1 for example.

Is it something related to Google Play Services that maybe is not installed on the other devices?

Is there something wrong with my code?

[image: Here'sthe final result]

Here's my code:

```
package com.app.connexion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.datatype.AppData;
import com.datatype.OrderInfo;
import com.datatype.ShopInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.utils.GMapV2Direction;
import com.utils.RequestTask;
import com.utils.RequestTask1;
import com.utils.RequestTaskDelegate;
import com.utils.WebServiceMethod;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class DetailOrder extends FragmentActivity implements RequestTaskDelegate{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String request;
    String basket;
    ImageButton checkout;
    ProgressDialog prog;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    GMapV2Direction md;

    String toaddr = "";
    LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
    LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);
    String orderid,gps;
    PolylineOptions rectLine;
    ArrayList<ShopInfo> shops;
    ImageButton posbtn;
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.detailorderone);
        checkout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        orderid = getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
        gps = getIntent().getStringExtra("others");
        posbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        posbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mMap.clear();
                sendGPS();
                positionredraw();
            }
        });
        checkout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailProductVC.class);
                intent.putExtra("basket", basket);
                intent.putExtra("orderid", orderid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        prog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Processing...",true,false);
        RequestTask task = new RequestTask();
        task.delegate = this;
        request = WebServiceMethod.kCommandeInfosMethode;
        task.execute(request,orderid);
        getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public void positionredraw()
    {
        //prog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Processing...",true,false);
        viewmap1();
    }

    public void getCurrentPosition()
    {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        UiSettings ui = mMap.getUiSettings();
        ui.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.getMyLocation();
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            fromPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                /*
                mMap.clear();
                sendGPS();
                positionredraw();
                */
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format("Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            fromPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            //fromPosition = new LatLng(48.8966175,2.327197);
            Log.d("current",message);
        }
    }

    public void sendGPS()
    {
        Thread t;
        t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    sendGPSData();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void sendGPSData()
    {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("connexion",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String shopperid = shared.getString("shopperid", "");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post;
        post = new HttpPost(WebServiceMethod.serverurl);
        Log.d("gps", "send gps");       
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", WebServiceMethod.key));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secret", WebServiceMethod.secret));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("shopperid", shopperid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", String.valueOf(fromPosition.latitude)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", String.valueOf(fromPosition.longitude)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("act", WebServiceMethod.kUpdateShopperStatusMethode));        

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            //response = client.execute(post);      
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();        
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.d("gpsResult",str);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public void viewmap1()
    {
        LatLng from,to;

        //prog.dismiss();

        rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.BLUE);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fromPosition).title("Moi"));
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPosition).title("B"));      
        String[] gpss = gps.split("#");
        from = fromPosition;
        to = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < gpss.length - 1;i++)
        {
            to = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(gpss[i].split(",")[0]),Double.parseDouble(gpss[i].split(",")[1]));

            viewmap(from,to);
            from = to;
        }
        int len  = gpss.length - 1;
        viewmap(from,new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(gpss[len].split(",")[0]),Double.parseDouble(gpss[len].split(",")[1])));
        ArrayList<OrderInfo> orders = ((AppData)this.getApplication()).orders;
        for(int i = 0; i < gpss.length;i++)     
        {
            OrderInfo order = orders.get(i);
            to = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(gpss[i].split(",")[0]),Double.parseDouble(gpss[i].split(",")[1]));           
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(to).title(order.name));
        }

        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng((fromPosition.latitude + to.latitude)/2, (fromPosition.longitude + to.longitude)/2);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 13));
        mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
        try{
            for(int i = 0;i < shops.size();i++)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(shops.get(i).pos).title(shops.get(i).name));
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }


    public void viewmap(LatLng from,LatLng to)
    {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("connexion",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String type = shared.getString("type", "");
        md = new GMapV2Direction(type);


        //LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(13.685400079263206, 100.537133384495975); 
        Document doc;
        if(type.equals("0"))
            doc = md.getDocument(from, to, GMapV2Direction.MODE_WALKING);
        else
            doc = md.getDocument(from, to, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);

        /*
        int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
        String distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
        String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
        String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);
        */

        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void backgroundActivityComp(String response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(request.equals(WebServiceMethod.kCommandeInfosMethode))
        {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                String str = json.getString("Results");
                if(!str.equals("false"))
                {
                    json = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONObject gps = new JSONObject(json.getString("addr"));
                    JSONObject gps1 = new JSONObject(gps.getString("gps"));
                    toPosition = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(gps1.getString("latitude")),Double.parseDouble(gps1.getString("longitude")));            
                    toaddr = gps.getString("name");
                    basket = json.getString("basket");

                    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("connexion",MODE_PRIVATE);                  
                    RequestTask task = new RequestTask();
                    task.delegate = this;
                    request = WebServiceMethod.kShipInfosMethode;
                    task.execute(request,shared.getString("shipid", ""));
                    return;
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                prog.dismiss();
            }
            return;
        }

        if(request.equals(WebServiceMethod.kShipInfosMethode))
        {
            try{
                prog.dismiss();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                shops = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();
                if(!json.getString("Results").equals("false"))
                {
                    json = new JSONObject(json.getString("Results"));

                    //shops = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();
                    JSONArray jsons = new JSONArray(json.getString("shops"));
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsons.length();i++)
                    {
                        ShopInfo shop = new ShopInfo();
                        json = new JSONObject(jsons.get(i).toString());
                        shop.name = json.getString("name");
                        shop.pos = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(json.getString("latitude")),Double.parseDouble(json.getString("longitude")));
                        shops.add(shop);
                    }
                    viewmap1();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                prog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working properly on some devices?

Comment: the blue point that represents the user is not moving on the map when the user is physically moving. I don't know if it's related to how I've implemented it or if it's due to the devices

Answer (score 0):

I believe there were some updates with Google Maps, which were not applied on older devices. Try updating older devices, if not done so. Or just make another version of app  for older devices